# How can I make a Django REST framework /me/ call?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a `ViewSet`:

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows a user's profile to be viewed or edited.
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

...and a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

I have my `urls.py` set up as:

```
router.register(r'profiles', api.ProfileViewSet, base_name='profile')
```

This lets me access e.g. `/api/profile/1/` fine.

I want to set up a new endpoint on my API (similar to the Facebook API's `/me/` call) at `/api/profile/me/` to access the current user's profile - how can I do this with Django REST Framework?

Comment: im not familiar with the rest framework of facebook but i think you are confusing the api with the webapp. a rest api should not be used by endusers only developers.

Comment: it's nothing to to with Facebook - I was just using FB's api as an example of what I want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new method in your view class using the `list_route` decorator, like:

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @list_route()
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # assumes the user is authenticated, handle this according your needs
        user_id = request.user.id
        return self.retrieve(request, user_id)
```

See the [docs on this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) for more info on `@list_route`

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am unable to get this to work: `Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly.`. Taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L51) it seems the `user_id` is not used (`*args`)

Comment: The ``pk`` (user id) is obtained from the ``kwargs`` in method ``GenericAPIView.get_object``. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41964640/4470542)

Answer (score 5):

Using the solution by @Gerard was giving me trouble:

```
Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly..
```

Taking a look at the [source code for retrieve()](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L51) it seems the `user_id` is not used (unused `*args`)

This solution is working:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

from ..serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    User = get_user_model()
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('username', 'email', 'usertype')
    search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'usertype')

    @list_route(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.object = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Accessing `/api/users/me` replies with the same data as `/api/users/1` (when the logged-in user is user with `pk=1`)

Comment: This worked for me. Didn't need to assign `self.object`, not sure what that's for.

Comment: Would this work if I want my others detail_routes on the ViewSet to work? Like `/api/users/me/activate` if activate is a detail_route.

Comment: This is fragile code. What if `retrieve()` code changes? Then the *me* endpoint will be giving different data.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the get_queryset method by filtering the queryset by the logged in user, this will return the logged in user's profile in the list view (/api/profile/).

```
def get_queryset(self):        
    return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

or

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ProfileViewSet, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

or override the retrieve method like so, this will return the profile of the current user.

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.request.user)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - what if I don't want change the behaviour of `/api/profile`? I still want this to show the list view as normal.  I just want the detail view to be able to lookup based on an integer (e.g. `/profile/1/`) or based on `/me/`.

Comment: The /profile/1/ is the retrieve method so that will return the Profile with pk=1 or which ever value you pass to it by default.

Comment: OK - but I would like to be able to pass the value "me" to the retrieve method to return the profile of the currently logged in user. So if I am e.g. user with pk=43 then `GET /api/profile/me/` will return the same as `GET /api/profile/43/`

Comment: Updated my answer, that is how you can override the retrieve method to return the current logged in user's details

Answer (score 2):

From [Gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937271/gerard)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172876/4470542) and looking at the error pointed out by [delavnog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647991/delavnog), I developed the following solution:

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @list_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])        
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs.update(pk=request.user.id)
        return self.retrieve(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

Notes:

- ModelViewSet inherits [GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself) and the logic to get an object is implemented in there.
- You need to check if the user is authenticated, otherwise request.user will not be available. Use at least `permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]`.
- This solution is for GET but you may apply the same logic for other methods.
- DRY assured!

Answer (score 2):

Just override the `get_object()`

eg.

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

Comment: This is the best way to do this if you're creating a separate viewset or view for the current user detail.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing a different way. I did it like this:

```
def get_object(self):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    if pk == 'me':
        return self.request.user
    else:
        return super().get_object()
```

This allows other detail_routes in the ViewSet to work like /api/users/me/activate

Answer (score 0):

I've seen quite a few fragile solutions so I thought I'll respond with something more up-to-date and safer. More importantly you don't need a separate view, since `me` simply acts as a redirection.

```py
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get', 'patch'])
    def me(self, request):
        self.kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk

        if request.method == 'GET':
            return self.retrieve(request)
        elif request.method == 'PATCH':
            return self.partial_update(request)
        else:
            raise Exception('Not implemented')
```

It's important to not duplicate the behaviour of `retrieve` like I've seen in some answers. What if the function `retrieve` ever changes? Then you end up with a different behaviour for `/me` and `/<user pk>`

If you only need to handle GET requests, you could also use Django's `redirect`. But that will not work with POST or PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a OneToOneField relationship between the `Profile` and the `User` models with `related_name='profile'`, I suggest the following as the `@list_route` has been [deprecated since DRF 3.9](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/)

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    @action(methods=('GET',), detail=False, url_path='me', url_name='me')
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.request.user.profile)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)
```