# Django REST calling reversed detail route cannot find kwargs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing 'users/me/'. (I alse read the [the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170848/how-can-i-make-a-django-rest-framework-me-call), but I'm try to add some specific function)

I made a function in `UserViewSet`:

```
@list_route()
def me(self, request):
    # ... find user ...
    request.path = reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'pk': user.id})
    self.partial_update(request)
```

It raises `` AssertionError: Expected view UserViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly. ``

`print(request.path)` is `/users/2/`, so `reverse` is working.

`urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
```

How could I deliver a pk? I have no idea what is the mistake I made.

UserViewSet code:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['patch'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def me(self, request):
        user = get_object_or_404(Token, key=request.auth).user

        request.path = reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'pk': user.id})
        self.partial_update(request, pk=user.id)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not implement it using a list_route but rather using another approach: overriding [`get_object(self)`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself) on the view:

```
def get_object(self):
    if self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_field, None) == 'me':
         # ... find user probably using self.get_queryset() or return self.request.user
         self.check_object_permissions(self.request, user) # may not be required, see get_object link
         return user

    return super().get_object()
```

This make you API react exactly the same whenever you use 'me' or the user pk and actions will be the same (get, put, patch, ... detailed_routes)

*Notes:*

- this only works if you are using a GenericView or subclass like ModelViewset
- I use python3 `super` syntax, do not forget to adapt it if you are using python2

Comment: I read about this( http://stackoverflow.com/a/38462877/2957055 ) but I want to set another permission on /me/ request. This is main reason of implementing list_route.

Comment: I guess then that instead of calling `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, user)`, you can implement your permissions there. From a general point of view I prefer the API to act the same whether you access it using '/{pk}/' or '/me/' as it is the same object you are requesting, but this may not  be the good approach to meet your requirements.